# How to fix the problem that items in a list do not belong to the list in atom editor?

Tags: python-3.x, list, atom-editor

I created a list that contains all the letters in alphebet in it, but the letters after "t" are all white and they seem not to be part of the list, does anyone know how to fix this problem?
[image]

Comment: Looks like it stops highlighting when the line is too long.

Comment: See https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1667